# Sending Ajax values to PHP not reading data on POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I've been trying lately to get some values (in this case, window's size) using JS and JQuery, and sending them to the PHP code that should echo them. The code below is working up to the `console.log(data)` function, since it writes down on the console the values of the screen width and height. The problem occours when I try to read and echo those values in PHP; it kinda feels like the PHP values are always empty and the code can't read them. I tried different kinds of Ajax calls (`.ajax({})`, `.post({})` ) but I couldn't get them to work.

Javascript Part:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () {

            var w = window.innerWidth;
            var h = window.innerHeight;
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'index.php',
                data: 
                    {
                        width: w,
                        height: h
                    },
                    success: function( data ) 
                    {
                        console.log( data );

                    }
            });

        });
```

PHP Part:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['width']) && isset($_POST['height'])) //THIS IS NEVER WORKING, THE PHP DOESN'T RECIVE THE $_POST DATA .
{
    $w = $_POST['width'];
    $h = $_POST['height'];
    echo $w."x".$h;
}
else
{
    echo "Error"; //So this is always false and echo the error message.
}
?>
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: can you make a quick test with `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's inside the $_POST

Comment: Inspect the actual requests in browser dev tool network to see what is actually sent. Would be a good idea to put some throttling on this. A manual resize will cause a lot of useless requests to be made

Comment: This is working for me, make sure you have jQuery loaded. If you're using Chrome/Firefox hit f12 and look at the network and console tabs.